# EventStoreDB Catch-up subscription is disposed after reading first event

Tags: c#, .net, eventstoredb

I'm using the EventStore gRPC client for .NET. If I connect to an empty EventStore the connection persists and all events that get appended afterwards are published to the subscribing client.
When there are already events stored and I start the client, i.e. the client has to catch up to the current state, only the first event is being read and the connection is disposed.

[EventStoreDB console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpYbC.png)

Here is the configuration of the subscription.

```
await _client.SubscribeToAllAsync(
                FromAll.Start,
                async (subscription, @event, cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    // handle event
                },
                filterOptions: prefixStreamFilter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the subscription returned by `SubscribeToAllAsync` in a field, so it doesn't get disposed. When the subscription is disposed, it unsubscribes.

The usual way to run a subscription continuously is to host it inside a hosted service or background service (which is a hosted service anyway).

You can look at [my implementation](https://github.com/Eventuous/eventuous/blob/dev/src/EventStore/src/Eventuous.EventStore/Subscriptions/AllStreamSubscription.cs), but it might be a bit too complex to examine as it uses a few abstractions that are designed to support multiple subscription sources. You can also use [Eventuous subscriptions](https://eventuous.dev/docs/infra/esdb/#all-stream-subscription) (it's a NuGet package) as it takes care about a few things, which are kind of mandatory to do (drops, serialisation, etc).